# How to read the value of a WordPress $query associative array (hash) key

Tags: query

New to WordPress programming (coming from a more conventional environment) and trying to understand some of its "unique" qualities.

There is a directory page on our website and this code resides, that is in `functions.php`, tweaks the results if condition is true.

```
if( $query->is_post_type_archive( 'directory' ) ){ 
    ...//do stuff
}
```

I would like to know how to access the "value of `is_post_type_archive` that is "directory." When I use test for the value...

```
var_dumb($query->is_post_type_archive());
```

..I get `bool(true)` which makes sense. But how/where is the value  "directory" stored/passed/accessed?

Answer (score 1):

First up, the first thing you should do is read the [developer docs](https://developer.wordpress.org). This question touches on a lot of topics, and it's not going to be possible to explain them all in one answer.

Anyway, `directory` would be a [Custom Post Type](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/post-types/) registered by the theme or a plugin.

When a post type is [registered](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/post-types/registering-custom-post-types/) the developer can tell WordPress what the URL path for its archive should be.

WordPress will then create a [rewrite rule](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_rule/) so that when a user visits that URL, WordPress receives a parameter that tells it that the user is requesting the archive for that post type.

When the user visits that URL WordPress will query the posts it needs to show for that post type archive. It will do that with a [`WP_Query()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) object. As part of this query WordPress will set the `is_post_type_archive` property of that object to `true`, and the `post_type` property to `directory`.

Developers can change the behaviour of post queries using the `pre_get_posts` [filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/filters/). Since WordPress can run more than one post query on any given request, any functions used on this filter will receive the current `WP_Query` object as a parameter. The developer can then choose to modify the only the main query for the post type archive by checking if `$query->is_post_type_archive( 'directory' )` is `true` for the current query.

Comment: Helpful, and 'yes', have spent hours in the docs (RTFM) but I'm trying to figure out what `is_post_type_archive()` is "looking at" to determine whether the post type is "directory" or not. I.e., how is the post type passed to functions.php. It's not in the $query. Is it the referring page? (Sorry, used to reading post and get headers in CGI)

Comment: I explained that?

Answer (score 0):

You found a regular WordPress object, `$query`, which is well documented in the [Code Reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/) on [its own page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/is_post_type_archive/):

> `WP_Query::is_post_type_archive( mixed $post_types = '' )`
>
> Is the query for an existing post type archive page?
>
> ### Description
>
> #### Parameters
>
> **$post_types**
> (mixed) (Optional) Post type or array of posts types to check against.
>
> Default value: ''

The [source code](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/is_post_type_archive/#source) is given there as well. So what does `is_post_type_archive($post_types)` do?

- `is_post_type_archive()` returns `true` if the current page is a post type archive of any kind
- `is_post_type_archive('foo')` returns `true` if the current page if a post type archive for the [(custom) post type](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/post-types/) `foo` (could be `post`, `page`, etc)
- `is_post_type_archive(['foo', 'bar'])` returns `true` if the current page is a post type archive for any of those (custom) post types  `foo`, `bar`.

Comment: I'm not sure that your "strictly speaking" point at the end there is correct. It's based on the `post_type` property of the query object, which is set based on what was queried. If specific post types were queried, those would be the values, or it would be `any` if that was queried.

Comment: @JacobPeattie You're right, I misread the code